# Is there any type of file that is unsafe to allow client to upload on Google Storage (S3)?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

The head question pretty much states everything. Is there any type of file that is unsafe to allow client to upload on Google Storage (S3)? For instance, you wouldn't want to allow any executable files on your server (FTP), but since no files (afaik) can be executed on Google Storage (S3) there is no need to implement any file filter?

Answer (score 2):

S3 is Amazon Storage, not Google Storage.

And there is no unsafe type to upload. The S3 container is safe.

If you find a flaw, you can probably claim a lot of money from Google. Or Amazon, I forgot.

Comment: S3 does not care what you upload. It's your data.